# Can training a model on a dataset composed by real images and drawings hurt the training process of a real-world application model?

Tags: image, deep-learning, classification, training-data

I'm training a classifier that's supposed to be tested on underwater images. I'm wondering if feeding the model drawings of a certain class plus real images can affect the results. Was there a study on this? Or are there any past experiences anyone could share to help?

Comment: I think you'll have more chance to get an answer in the artificiel intelligence site : https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TontonVelu Thank you I'll repost my question there as well